# Dynamic numbers of fields depending on values of another field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have form and it look like this:

```
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    <label for="id_rooms">Rooms:</label>
    <input id="id_rooms" type="number" name="rooms" min="1">
</div>

<div class="extrafieldWrapper">    
</div>
```

And I have script that add or delete couple of fields 'adult' and 'children' depending on value of field 'room'. Now i want to do the same thing with field 'children': depending on value of field 'children' script should add or delete fields 'children_age'. I tried to realize it something like this, but it isn't work.

```
$(function () {
   $('#id_rooms').bind('blur keyup change', function () {
      var n = $('#id_rooms').val() || 0;
      $("input[id='id_form-TOTAL_FORMS']").attr('value', n);
      $(".extrafieldWrapper").empty();
      for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
         $(".extrafieldWrapper").append("<br/><label for='id_form-" + i + "-adult'>Adult:</label> <input id='id_form-" + i + "-adult' type='number' name='form-" + i + "-adult'/> <label for='id_form-" + i + "-children'>Children:</label> <input id='id_form-" + i + "-children' type='number'  name='form-" + i + "-children'/><div id='extrafieldWrapperChAge'></div>");
             $("#id_form" + i + "children").bind('blur keyup change', function() {
                 var n = $("#id_form" + i + "children").val() || 0;
                 $(".extrafieldWrapperChAge").empty();
                 for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    $(".extrafieldWrapperChAge").append("<br/><label for='id_form-" + i + "-childrenage'></label><input id='id_form-" + i + "-childrenage' type='number' name='form-" + i + "childrenage' />");
                 }
              });
           }
        });
    });
```

I am newbie in java-script, can you tell me what i'm doing wrong. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I suggest you start by refactoring your code. Extract the inner code to another method. You have nested for-loops with counter i and two variables n in nested blocks. That is pretty confusing and error prone.

Comment: where you define this id id_form-TOTAL_FORMS your html?

Comment: can you show your complete html ?

Comment: id_form-TOTAL_FORMS is created by Django - framework that I use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract your inner code and use only one event handler for the childrens age field(s). In the code below I have added the class children_age to the input fields and then attached a event handler to listening for changes on all elements with that class.

Note 1: It should be enough to listen for change events.
Note 2: Use **on** instead of **bind** since it's recommended by the jQuery team

```
$(function(){

  $('#id_rooms').on('change', function(e){

    var n = $('#id_rooms').val() || 0;
    var html = "";

      for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        html += "<br/><label for='id_form-" + i + "-adult'>Adult:</label>"
             + "<input id='id_form-" + i + "-adult' type='number' name='form-" + i + "-adult'/>"
             + "<label for='id_form-" + i + "-children'>Children:</label>"
             + "<input id='id_form-" + i + "-children' type='number' name='form-" + i + "-children' class='children_age'/>"
             + "<div class='extrafieldWrapperChAge'></div>";
      }
      $(".extrafieldWrapper").html(html);
  });

  $(".extrafieldWrapper").on('change', '.children_age', function(e){

    // $(this) refers to the element that changed
    var n = $(this).val() || 0;
    var html = "";

      for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        html += "<br/><label for='id_form-" + i + "-childrenage'>Age of child "+(i+1)+"</label>"
             + "<input id='id_form-" + i + "-childrenage' type='number' name='form-" + i + "childrenage' />";
      }
      //.next - finds the next occurrence that matches the selector
      $(this).next('.extrafieldWrapperChAge').html(html);
  });

});
```